# inserting images into mysql

Tags: mysql, image

I am trying to learn how to use mysql but am having trouble building an image database. In essence the following code:

```
UPDATE pic SET img = LOAD_FILE( 'C:\Users\name\Pictures\marketbear3.jpg' ) WHERE idpic =1
```

kicks back -> 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0007 sec)

my table name is 'pic' and the columns are 'idpic' 'caption' and 'img'...I tried to follow the steps at [this website.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914)

Please help...

Comment: Last time I checked, it is not a best practice to store the images in a database. Can you store your images in a file directory then point to the location from the db field? Or maybe you are just asking this because you are messing around with code, which is great. Just my two cents.

Comment: You are trying to learn how to use mysql wrong way.

Comment: the down votes really don't help...how would I "point" though...what is the syntax for that sort of operation? @snowYetis yes I am messing with code, but I also want to use it for an actual db.

Comment: @acegreene2 There is no such thing as a bad question unless you are on Stackoverflow. You are half way there. Your table should have an ID (Identity Seed/Unique ID/Primary Key), then a field with the directory as you have in your question above. You should probably also have a field that will allow you to grab x image from the db from your app. When you pull this directory location in your app, have the code grab the image and assign it to an image tag.

Comment: either escape your backslashes or better use forward slashes `LOAD_FILE( 'C:/Users/name/Pictures/marketbear3.jpg' )`?

Comment: @snowYetis, thanks, idpic is my ID.  your lose me on " a field with the directory" Is this the same thing as me setting up a column named "directory" for example?

Comment: @bansi good catch...that was a left over from copy/pasting from properties pop up

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
UPDATE pic SET img = LOAD_FILE( 'C:/Users/name/Pictures/marketbear3.jpg' ) WHERE idpic =1
```

or

```
UPDATE pic SET img = LOAD_FILE( 'C:\\Users\\name\\Pictures\\marketbear3.jpg' ) WHERE idpic =1
```

Backslash is special character for escaping the next character so `\n` is actually a newline.